# Getting data from XML in android studio

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

My aim is to access the xml file and get the No present inside the xml file.
I want access data from my xml which is in local storage but i am not able to access the values getting errors at xpath.Kindly help me

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sample>
<Sample1>
    <NO>257</LastPage>
</sample1>
<Sample2>
    <NO>257</LastPage>
</sample2>
</Sample>
```

Class File:

```
AssetManager manager = getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = manager.open("PageDetails.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = 
 DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder =  builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(inputStream);

        XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        String expression = "/Bhajans/"+bookPath;
        Node lastpageNO = (Node) xPath.evaluate(expression, xmlDocument,  
 XPathConstants.NODE);
        Log.d("Displaying page No:","number"+lastpageNO);
```

Error:

```
06-06 12:10:04.119  30072-30072/com.com.sample.samples W/System.err﹕ javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Extra illegal tokens: '5'
06-06 12:10:04.119  30072-30072/com.com.sample.samples W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:295)
```

Comment: Is it correct xml??? coz i dont think its correct xml

Comment: can you suggest me whats wrong in it....forget about tags......i just changed it sample to paste it here....if there is any wrong in format plz do mention it to me.....ty

Answer (score 2):

You need to create xml parser as suggested in this tutorial
[xml parser android](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm)

Also you can create xml file under xml directory of android folder structure. The xml directory would be parallel to res folder. You need to create this file manually. And then you can excess R>xl.yourfile or your constant.
And the xml you pasted has syntactical error.

The correct xml should be:

```
<Sample>
<Sample1>
    <NO>257</No>
</sample1>
<Sample2>
    <NO>257</No>
</sample2>
</Sample>
```